# Trigger mouseenter and mouseleave for repeating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am fetching data from MySql and I am displaying it in a table. I would like that for each `<td>` that contains a certain `id` to display some extra info on `mouseenter` and hide it on `mouseleave` using jQuery. Here is the HTML output:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Option 1</th>
            <th>Option 2</th>
            <th>Option 3</th>
        </tr>
<?php   
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>  
    <tr>
        <td id="triggerTooltip"><?php echo $row['option1']; ?>
            <div class="tooltip">
                <p>Extra info</p>
            </div>
        </td>                   
        <td><?php echo $row['option2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['option3']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The default `display` property for the tool-tip is set to `none`. Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
$('#triggerTooltip').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).closest('.tooltip').show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).closest('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

I tried using `$(this).find('.tooltip')` and it works, but only for the first occurrence of the `#triggerTooltip`. I think I am getting it wrong. Can you please help me to figure this out? Thank you.

Comment: Also `$(this).closest('.tooltip')` and `$(this).find('.tooltip')` are two completely different things. The first looks up. The second looks down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above answer is correct here, this behaviour could also be implemented with CSS if you wanted, with a rule like:

```
.triggerTooltip .tooltip {
    display: none;
}

.triggerTooltip:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It really helps me not depending in JS for this. Simple and clear.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are duplicating (or *n*plicating) ids. Don't duplicate ids! Use classnames instead.

```
$('.triggerTooltip').mouseenter(function() {
     $(this).find('.tooltip').show();  
}).mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).find('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

### HTML

```
   <td class="triggerTooltip"><?php echo $row['option1']; ?>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <p>Extra info</p>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jquery hover](https://devdocs.io/jquery/hover), which takes two functions as arguments, and remember that classes and IDs are different. IDs are meant to be unique on a page.

Comment: Thank you! This is a neat approach, I will keep it in mind for future use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#triggerTooltip').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('.tooltip').each(function() {$(this).show()});
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.tooltip').each(function() {$(this).hide()});
});
```